# SQLC []byte array not getting inserted in postgres for jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlc

I'm new to sqlc and go. I have a jsonb column in postgres. When I do '''sqlc generate''', the types generated are []byte array exactly what the SQLC documentation says. But the problem I have is the geneated function which should be inserting the '''[]byte''' into postgress column is throwing error as Not a valid JSON type. From my little understanding the []byte has to be converted to jsonb again. But I guess I can't edit the geneated code as it will generate again if I regenerate.

Even if I make a custom struct to say SQLC to not generate jsonb as '''[]byte''' instead the custom type. Here also I assume I ll somehow need to convert that struct to jsonb which postgres will allow inserting.

Stuck on this. Is there any solution to it?

Slqc generation

```
-- name: CreateTeamUser :one
INSERT INTO team_users (
    meta_jsonb,

) VALUES (
  $1
) RETURNING *;
```

Slql genarated code after `sqlc generate`

```
type CreateTeamUserParams struct {
    Meta_jsonb   []byte      `json:"meta_jsonb"`
}

func (q *Queries) CreateTeamUser(ctx context.Context, arg CreateTeamUserParams) (TeamUser, error) {
    row := q.db.QueryRow(ctx, createTeamUser,
        arg.Meta_jsonb,
    )
    var i TeamUser
    err := row.Scan(
        &i.ID,
        &i.Meta_jsonb
    )
    return i, err
}
```

This is how I'm calling

```
arg := db.CreateTeamUserParams{
            Meta_jsonb:   user.GetMeta_Jsonb(),
        }

        _, err := server.store.CreateTeamUser(ctx, arg)
```

Data Im passing

```
{"meta_jsonb": {"name": "me"}}
```

Error Im getting

```
ERR received a HTTP request body="{\"code\":13,\"message\":\"failed to create user: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json (SQLSTATE 22P02)\"}"
```

Comment: Please show us how you are calling the generated function (are you passing valid JSON?), the query used to generate the sqlc function, and the full error text (postgres will return an error if the JSON is not valid).

Comment: @Brits updated the question with code, could you check this out?

Comment: Please replace `user.GetMeta_Jsonb()` with ```[]byte(`{"meta_jsonb": {"name": "me"}}`)``` (as we cant see `GetMeta_Jsonb()` I want to ensure I understand what this is actually doing as I'd expect it to work; any issues in the JSON will lead to the error you are seeing e.g. a missing `}`).